# Having rails bi-directional modeling issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a class: Artist

```
 class Artist < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, through: :album_artists

  has_many :tracks, through: :albums

  has_many :related_artists

end
```

And an associated class called related_artist

```
class RelatedArtist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :related_artist, class_name: 'Artist'

  after_create :create_inverse, unless: :has_inverse?
  after_destroy :destroy_inverses, if: :has_inverse?

  def create_inverse
    self.class.create(inverse_related_options)
  end

  def destroy_inverses
    inverses.destroy_all
  end

  def has_inverse?
    self.class.exists?(inverse_related_options)
  end

  def inverses
    self.class.where(inverse_related_options)
  end

  def inverse_related_options
    { related_artist_id: artist_id, artist_id: related_artist_id }
  end

end
```

Here is the related table:

```
class CreateRelatedArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :related_artists do |t|
      t.references :artist, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :related_artist, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_foreign_key :related_artists, :artists, column: :related_artist_id
    add_index :related_artists, [:artist_id, :related_artist_id,], unique: true
  end
end
```

I run the following: `beatles.related_artists.create!(related_id:71)` to create the association.

I can check `beatles.related_artists` and see `#<RelatedArtist id: 7, artist_id: 63, related_artist_id: 71, created_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09", updated_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09">`.

However, I can't iterate through the collection and get to a list of artists i.e. `beatles.related_artists.each do |ra| ...`

What am I missing?

Comment: when you do beatles.related_artists do you get a single item or an array?  What error do you get when you try beatles.related_artists.each do....?

Comment: When I do beatles.related_artists I get: #<RelatedArtist id: 7, artist_id: 63, related_artist_id: 71, created_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09", updated_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09">. If I do the each.do - and then try to access an attribute such as artist.name, i get a undefined method `name' for #<RelatedArtist:0x00007f994aa3d8e8>.. It doesn't do the conversion to the associated class.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can i request you run something like `puts beatles.related_artists.inspect` - the inspect is important. Also try `beatles.related_artists.each { |ra|  puts ra.inspect }`

Comment: beatles.related_artists.inspect returns  RelatedArtist Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  `related_artists`.* FROM `related_artists` WHERE `related_artists`.`artist_id` = 63 LIMIT 11
 => "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<RelatedArtist id: 7, artist_id: 63, related_artist_id: 71, created_at: \"2018-03-22 01:37:09\", updated_at: \"2018-03-22 01:37:09\">]>"

Comment: beatles.related_artists.each { |ra| puts ra.inspect }
  RelatedArtist Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `related_artists`.* FROM `related_artists` WHERE `related_artists`.`artist_id` = 63
#<RelatedArtist id: 7, artist_id: 63, related_artist_id: 71, created_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09", updated_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09">
 => [#<RelatedArtist id: 7, artist_id: 63, related_artist_id: 71, created_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09", updated_at: "2018-03-22 01:37:09">] 
2.5.0 :011 >

Comment: So - I ended up destroying the related_artists model and starting over. I felt like the association and the class should be named differently. So I called it match - and matched_artist -- adding this one line to Artist class: has_many :matches
  has_many :matched_artists, through: :matches and now it works!